# PHP, Eclipse, Remote Debugging, CentOS, 57%

Tags: php, eclipse, xdebug

I have a Mac (10.8.3) dev machine connecting to a CentOS (6.3) VM running PHP 5.4.13 under Eclipse June Service Release 2.

I am running into the dreaded "Launching test (57%)..." hang issue.  I have looked all over the web/stack overflow and there seem to be a bunch of suggestions (which I tried, none of which seemed to fix my issue).

My /etc/php.ini file looks like this:

```
[xdebug]
zend_extension=/usr/lib64/php/modules/xdebug.so
xdebug.remote_enable=On
xdebug.remote_handler="dbgp"
xdebug.remote_mode="req"
xdebug.remote_port=9000
xdebug.remote_host="10.211.55.3"
xdebug.remote_log=/tmp/xdebug_remote_log
xdebug.remote_connect_back=0
```

My /etc/php.d/xdebug.ini file looks like this:

```
; Enable Xdebug extension module
extension=xdebug.so

; Configure the extension [See Xdebug documentation for options to add here]
xdebug.remote_enable=On
xdebug.remote_handler="dbgp"
xdebug.remote_mode="req"
xdebug.remote_port=9000
xdebug.remote_host="10.211.55.3"
xdebug.remote_log=/tmp/xdebug_remote_log
xdebug.remote_connect_back=0


$ php -i | grep -i xdebug
/etc/php.d/xdebug.ini,
xdebug
xdebug support => enabled
xdebug.auto_trace => Off => Off
xdebug.cli_color => 0 => 0
xdebug.collect_assignments => Off => Off
xdebug.collect_includes => On => On
xdebug.collect_params => 0 => 0
xdebug.collect_return => Off => Off
xdebug.collect_vars => Off => Off
xdebug.coverage_enable => On => On
xdebug.default_enable => On => On
xdebug.dump.COOKIE => no value => no value
xdebug.dump.ENV => no value => no value
xdebug.dump.FILES => no value => no value
xdebug.dump.GET => no value => no value
xdebug.dump.POST => no value => no value
xdebug.dump.REQUEST => no value => no value
xdebug.dump.SERVER => no value => no value
xdebug.dump.SESSION => no value => no value
xdebug.dump_globals => On => On
xdebug.dump_once => On => On
xdebug.dump_undefined => Off => Off
xdebug.extended_info => On => On
xdebug.file_link_format => no value => no value
xdebug.idekey => no value => no value
xdebug.max_nesting_level => 100 => 100
xdebug.overload_var_dump => On => On
xdebug.profiler_aggregate => Off => Off
xdebug.profiler_append => Off => Off
xdebug.profiler_enable => Off => Off
xdebug.profiler_enable_trigger => Off => Off
xdebug.profiler_output_dir => /tmp => /tmp
xdebug.profiler_output_name => cachegrind.out.%p => cachegrind.out.%p
xdebug.remote_autostart => Off => Off
xdebug.remote_connect_back => Off => Off
xdebug.remote_cookie_expire_time => 3600 => 3600
xdebug.remote_enable => On => On
xdebug.remote_handler => dbgp => dbgp
xdebug.remote_host => 10.211.55.3 => 10.211.55.3
xdebug.remote_log => /tmp/xdebug_remote_log => /tmp/xdebug_remote_log
xdebug.remote_mode => req => req
xdebug.remote_port => 9000 => 9000
xdebug.scream => Off => Off
xdebug.show_exception_trace => Off => Off
xdebug.show_local_vars => Off => Off
xdebug.show_mem_delta => Off => Off
xdebug.trace_enable_trigger => Off => Off
xdebug.trace_format => 0 => 0
xdebug.trace_options => 0 => 0
xdebug.trace_output_dir => /tmp => /tmp
xdebug.trace_output_name => trace.%c => trace.%c
xdebug.var_display_max_children => 128 => 128
xdebug.var_display_max_data => 512 => 512
xdebug.var_display_max_depth => 3 => 3
$
```

Any help here would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

my experience using PHP eclipse shows me the following scenarios with this behaviour:

1 - The website I am trying to debug is not working properly. By this I mean, if we have an internal error, for example, the apache will not run the site and will not be possible to debug it.
2 - The client machine is not allowed to get xdebug information. this happens often when we have a DHCP server and often changes the remote host IP.

So, make sure the website you are trying to run is running outside eclipse debugging. Open it in a browser and see if it is running.
Also, make sure the eclipse machine has the IP you informed on xdebug.remote_host parameter.